# Poor std::atomic performance on Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, c++

I recently migrated a project of mine from Pi 3B+ to Pi 4B only to find that it now runs much slower than before. After investigation, it appears the culprit is the atomic library that I use heavily. Indeed, after making a small benchmark with identical code (that pits two threads against each other endlessly storing and loading from an atomic int) on both platforms, I get these results:

~12M load/store cycles per second on Pi 3

~6.5M on Pi 4

I tried using std::memory_order_relaxed which would be fine in my case but there is no difference on either platform.

To rule out any actual CPU issues, I ran a quick math benchmark and the Pi 4 was 50% faster.

Does anyone know how I can address this? An alternative library perhaps? I don't know if it matters but the atomic library must be explicitly linked on Pi 4 (-latomic) but not on 3.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a power supply problem?  The Pi4B needs more power to prevent CPU throttling.

Comment: @joan I tried supplying through the GPIO and USB-C with 5V 3A when I ran the benchmark. Is throttling reflected in CPU stats from 'top'? When I run the test it shows 200%.

Comment: Two ideas: 1st) the -latomic observation let's me assume that you use different compiler (versions) or c++ versions. Atomic is commonly in the standard lib. If you use a different compiler or c++ the time consumption may vary. Probably you work with different optimization levels. 2nd) The Pi4 speed is nearly one halve of the Pi3 speed. That could be because you use one core on the Pi4 and two cores on the Pi3 for the two threads that you are running. Taking the thread switching into account the times seem plausible. These are guesses, but who knows?

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer 1) gcc 6.3 vs gcc 8.3, no explicit optimizations. I should look a bit closer at this. 2) 'top' shows 200% CPU usage on both pis. Single threaded arithmetic shows the Pi 4 being much faster.

Comment: There is a console tool called htop, that shows you the load of each CPU core.  If on the pi3 the two threads that store and read an atomic int are distributed to two CPU cores, the load is also distributed to the two separate  running cores. Let's assume the two threads are performed on one CPU core on the pi4, then the core has to deal with all the load and additionally the core has two switch the threads. That switching is not as expensive as for processes but it uses time. A single thread prog. can not be distributed to two cores (on both pis), so the performance can be compared directly.